# VueJS: how can i use two computed properties inside one v-for?

Tags: filter, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this computed property:

```
 computed: {
            filteredCars: function() {
                var self = this
                return self.carros.filter(function(carro) {
                    return carro.nome.indexOf(self.busca) !== -1
                })
            },
        },
```

and i'm using v-for like this:

```
<tr v-for="carro in filteredCars">
    <td>{{carro.nome}}</td>
    <td>{{carro.marca}}</td>
    <td>{{carro.categoria}}</td>
    <td>{{carro.motor}}</td>
    <td>{{carro.cambio}}</td>
    <td>{{carro.preco}}</td>
 </tr>
```

but I need to create another computed property to limit my data quantity, how i call it inside the same v-for?

I'm trying to use *filteredCars* + another filter, in this case something like 'limit' filter from vue 1.x. I've done an example using Vue 1.x but i need to do using Vue 2.x.

```
Vue.filter('limit', function (value, amount) {
            return value.filter(function(val, index, arr){
                return index < amount;      
            });

<tr v-for="carro in carros | limit upperLimit>
...
</tr>
```

Comment: Create another computed that returns, say `filteredCars.slice(1, 30)` or some such and use that instead.

Comment: Can you explain what it is **exactly** that you want to do?

Comment: @RoyJ it is, but this is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Array.prototype.slice` (`Array.prototype.splice` should work too) in the computed property.

```
data: {
    carros: [...],
    upperLimit: 30
},
computed: {
    filteredCars: function() {
        const arr = this.carros.filter(function(carro) {
            return carro.nome.indexOf(self.busca) !== -1
        });
        if (arr.length > this.upperLimit) {
            return arr.slice(0, this.upperLimit + 1);
        }
        return arr;
    },
}
```